# Toolbar and Statusbar collide while moving from Full screen Activity to Non Full screen Activity

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

Hi Please see the attached video to understand the problem

[Video](https://youtu.be/OiYzuZhxzxY)

SplashScreenActivity

```
    public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        findViewById(R.id.txt_skip).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Styles

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Theme for Splash with no Action bar full screen -->
<style name="splash_screen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Styles/v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
</style>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/splash_screen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

</application>
```

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Demo App"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem ??

Comment: hey can you post mainActivity layout file?

Comment: I have added it, can you please have a look at it

Comment: can you try my solution if still struggling with issue?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and saw that when **MainActivity** is opening after skip button click in **SplashActivity**, the system starts draw status bar but not immediately , as  it  is opening in some animation, till then **MainActivity** layout get the whole screen canvas to draw itself.After trying few minutes for fix in themes or styles, where I did not succeed, I came up with a hack that, show status bar just before starting **MainActivity**, so that **MainActivity**'s layout doesn't get full screen canvas for drawing itself.

You can try this hack too.

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        findViewById(R.id.txt_skip).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                }
                else {                       
                    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
                    getWindow().getDecorView().decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
                }                
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Let me know if this solved your problem or not?

Comment: I added your code, now the splash screen strucks but the mainactivity looks Okay

Comment: Yeah.. you can remove status bar pragmatically each  time  in onCreate of SpalshActivity. By the way do you allow user to come back  to SplashScreen on backpress from mainActivity?? is this useful?

Comment: I dnt allow user to splash on backpress from main activity. But I need splash screen to be full screen, it shouldn't contain status bar

Comment: SplashScreen will be without statusbar each time you open the app, It shows statusbar only once user click skip text as in your code. I have  tested it with code shared with you above.  Keep the theme as full-screen  for SplashActivity.

Comment: I need statusbar for splashscreen